# How to properly store dates in Cassandra [java]?

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data

I have the following entity:

```
    @Table("room_booked_by_guest_and_date")
    public class RoomByGuestAndDate {
        @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "guest_id", type = PARTITIONED)
        private UUID guestId;
        @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "booking_date", type = CLUSTERED, ordering = DESCENDING)
        private Date bookingDate;
        @Column("roomNumber")
        private Integer roomNumber;
        @Column("hotel_id")
        private UUID hotelId;
        @Column("confirmation_number")
        private String confirmationNumber;
     }
```

I would like to store it using the Spring Data for C* (`CassandraRepository<RoomByGuestAndDate>`)
When I do the save, I get the following exception:

```
"Expected 4 byte long for date (8); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Expected 4 byte long for date (8)"
```

When I change the `Date` to the DataStax `LocalDate`, I get another exception that the `LocalDate cannot be cast to the Serializable`.

So, the question is how can I properly persist this Java POJO to the C* column family?